Wordpress Elementor Pro Gallery not loading images - Bundle webpack file versions are different?
In Wordpress, Elementor Pro, I have a Gallery. The photos suddenly stopped showing.
From the JS Console it shows:
Uncaught (in promise) ChunkLoadError: Loading chunk gallery failed.
In the folder wp-content/plugins/elementor-pro/assets/js:
There is a file: gallery.805130d33e18cb04635f.bundle.js
But server is asking for gallery.b7d55bc976e04f751975.bundle.js
Is this a webpack issue? How do I resolve this please?
I tried clearing the cache, and Elementor Regenerate CSS and data, but no luck so far.
I did reinstall a plugin this morning: Powerpack Lite for Elementor
Any ideas on how to solve this?
